# What is preventing me from using $_ in a pipeline?

Tags: git, powershell

The command `git branch --list | select-string 2362` gives me a list of several branches that fit the pattern `2362`.  I want to delete all of those branches on the server.

The command `git branch --list | select-string 2362 | git push origin --delete $_` gives me the error `fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs`, which is the same error I get from the command `git push origin --delete`.  It is as though $_ is empty, as though there are no branches found which match the pattern.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of issues with what you're trying to do. The `git` command doesn't accept pipeline input (as far as I know) because its not a PowerShell cmdlet.

Also `Select-String` returns a MatchInfo object, so `$_` wouldn't contain just the name of the branches, but this object with its various properties.

Try this:

```
(git branch --list | select-string 2362).line | ForEach-Object {
    git push origin --delete $_
}
```

Beware though that you might get a * character in one of the branch names if its the current branch.

Comment: Adding the `.matches.value` doesn't work -- it makes the result of that part always equal to '2362'.

Comment: Hmm... Now I'm getting an odd "fatal: invalid refspec ':  feature/DEVO-2362-1'", which is odd, because the prefix ':  ' is not part what I get from the command (git branch --list | select-string 2362).line

Comment: @PortMan: `git branch -list`  outputs some whitespace at the start of each line (and `*` for the active branch). You have to filter that out. And `:branch` is the traditional delete syntax which is confused by that space. So use `git branch --list --format="%(refname:strip=2)" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this "one-liner":

```
git branch --list | ? { $_ -like "*2362*" } | Select-Object -first 1 | % {
    git push origin --delete ($_ -replace "[:\*]",  " ").Trim()  
}
```

`Select-Object` is used to only delete one branch, of course, it can be removed. Leading star and `:` gets replaced. Spaces are trimmed.

Hope that helps